# how to get child item object while adding to cart?

Tags: addtocart, magento2.4, quantity, quoteitem, stock-availability

I wanna put customize the code with qty while adding to cart product.
For that I have created Plugin `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` and used `addQty()` method,but in this method I call `quoteItem` object. Below code working fine for simple product,but for configurable product it is not working.

Below I have created two files to customize code.
I have created one plugin. Here is `di.xml` file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
        <plugin name="test_customizationquote_item" type="Test\CustomizationQuote\Plugin\Model\Quote\Item" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**workflow**

At front store, when I select color of configurable product and click to add to cart button. It comes in `addQty()` method with requested qty. In this function I call `quoteItem` object,but this `quoteItem` object get parent item object or data rather than get child item.
My goal is when before add to cart item, I need to check quantity of item,but `quoteItem` object fetch parent item object so I am unable to fetch child item stock qty. So How can I get child product object in `addQty()` function.

I have written `addQty()` function in below code. please check it

Then Here is my plugin code `Item.php`

```
<?php

namespace Test\CustomizationQuote\Plugin\Model\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item as QuoteItem;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock;

class Item
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var StockRegistryInterface
     */
    private $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function beforeAddQty(QuoteItem $quoteItem, $qty)
    {
        $product = $quoteItem->getProduct(); // here I am getting configurable product object instead of child product object
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());


        return [$qty];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing out $quoteItem to see if there are any product options there. For configurable products , Magento adds option codes (i-e color and size) along with parentId, to cart. If you can get selected options, hopefully you'll be able to get corresponding child product based on those option values.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getSku(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```